# How to calculate the average of a value in R in a loop

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this one:

```
Date_A  Date_B  Type Price
2345    2400    A    120
1115    1230    B    226
930     945     C    90
1050    1100    A    157
```

And I want to print the values from the Type column where the values of Date_A are less than Date_B. For this part I did the following code:

```
for(i in 1:length(list)){
      if(`Date_A`[i]<`Date_B`[i]){
        print(Type[i])
      }
    }
```

This code works fine. Now I want to calculate the total average of the Price column for the Type values that I printed before which were the Type's where Date_A < Date_B. I thought of doing something like:

```
for(i in 1:length(list)){
  if(`Date_A`[i]<`Date_B`[i]){
    print(Type[i])
    Price_Average[i] <- mean(Price)
  }
```

However this only gives me the total mean of the whole dataset and I want the mean of the price where Date_A < Date_B. I am trying to figure out how I could calculate this using loops since I am practicing loops in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want. Try this:

`mean(Price[Date_A < Date_B])`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to follow your question without sample data but I'll try.  The line

```
which(`Date_A` < `Date_B`)
```

should give you the indices of all rows where `Data A < Data B`.  So

```
Price[which(`Date_A` < `Date_B`)]
```

are all prices where `Data_A < Data_B`, and this will give you the answer:

```
mean(Price[which(`Date_A` < `Date_B`)])
```

Comment: Hi @lebelinoz, sorry for not putting a dataset sample in my question. I edited the question to try to make it more clear.

Comment: In that case, my answer still more-or-less stands.  If your dataframe is called `df`, you need to put a `df$` in front of each of the columns.  i.e. the final answer will be `mean(df$Price[which(df$Date_A < df$Date_B)])`

Comment: Might be a better example dataset if not all `Date_A` were less than `Date_B` :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a data frame named df with columns "Date_A","Date_B","Price", and in addition to above propositions, you can try:

`lg <- ifelse(df$Date_A<df$Date_B,TRUE,FALSE)
mean(df$Price[lg])`